# IPB shoutbox remove texteditor

Tags: ckeditor, ipb

I am really doubt that it is impossible to disable text editor in shoutbox (mode full or in popup window).
if i remove this (in shoutbox template):

```
{parse editor="shout_msg" content="" options="array( 'height' => 100 )"}
```

then editor is disabled, but i can't send any messages(no input fields).

The question is: how to disable any text editors in popup or full mode. ( for example in root mode only one text field and some buttons. but in full mode we have fully CKEditor or something else..). i want keep only one text input field and only..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. just replace Popup template ( shoutbox ) with  hookGlobalShoutbox template. and replace all $d with $data  will work. (also the javascript is needed to be inserted at the top)

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='public/js/shoutbox.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='public/sounds/soundmanager2-nodebug-jsmin.js'></script>
```

save and go..

but after that any shout edit cannot be done ..